# sort a list from highest to lowest

Tags: php

i have a script that posts the id's onto a page, the only problem is that it posts the highest id number last.

i would like it to post the highest id number first and the lowest last

heres my script

```
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">id</font></th> 

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");

<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
```

this code above does a great job of getting the id from my mysql db

if this makes no sense please tell me and ill try to explain is in another way

Comment: You can just add `ORDER BY id DESC` to your query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this at the end of your query

```
Order by Id Desc
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: the important part is the "ORDER BY id DESC"

Answer (score 2):

That should be done in your SQL query.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC;
```

The ORDER BY clause will do perfectly.